# Drawing line segment

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can you draw exactly this?

[image: Line Segment]

I tried this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\gratio{(1+sqrt(5))/2}
\def\lenB{2}
\path (0,0) node[coordinate](start){} ++(\gratio*\lenB,0)node[coordinate](a){} -- ++(\lenB,0)node[coordinate](b){};
\draw (start) --node[above] {$a$} (a) --node[above]{$b$} (b);
\foreach \n in {start,a,b}\draw (\n) ++(0,-2pt) -- ++(0,4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways. Here is one with a user-defined style called `tick` that includes the label below the tick mark.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{tick/.style={draw, minimum width=0pt, minimum height=2pt, inner sep=0pt, label=below:$#1$},
    tick/.default={}}

\pgfmathsetmacro\gratio{(1+sqrt(5))/2}
\newcommand{\lenB}{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) node[tick=C_2]{} -- ++(\lenB*\gratio,0) node[tick=C_1]{} 
     (\lenB,0) node[tick=A]{} -- ++(\lenB*\gratio,0) node[tick=B]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh, nice `[minimum width=0pt]`!

Answer (score 2):

This looks pretty much like your example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\x{5}
    \def\tick{0.05}

    \draw (0,0) -- (\x,0);
    \draw (0,\tick) -- ++(0,-2*\tick) node[below] {$C_2$};
    \draw (0.37*\x,\tick) -- ++(0,-2*\tick) node[below] {$A$};
    \draw (0.63*\x,\tick) -- ++(0,-2*\tick) node[below] {$C_1$};
    \draw (\x,\tick) -- ++(0,-2*\tick) node[below] {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that you missed the involved golden ratio in it.

Comment: True, it wasn't really specified in the question. Is the drawing in the question some standard text book drawing one should know, or how do you know how exactly it relates to the golden ratio?

Comment: I don't know but it seemed to me that it should be taken in account. Maybe OP would answer that question.

Answer (score 2):

@Sandy G gave a `node` way. Here is an alternative using `pic`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\gratio{(1+sqrt(5))/2}
\newcommand{\lenB}{2}
\tikzset{mytick/.pic={\draw[thick] (0,.08)--(0,-.08);}}
\draw 
(0,0)               pic[red]{mytick}     node[below=1pt]{$C_2$} -- 
++(\lenB*\gratio,0) pic[magenta]{mytick} node[below=1pt]{$C_1$}--
(\lenB,0)           pic[blue]{mytick}    node[below=1pt]{$A$} -- ++(\lenB*\gratio,0) pic[orange]{mytick}  node[below=1pt]{$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```